# How to implement SSO login with OIDC using React js

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Need help for implementing SSO login with OIDC connect using React js

Comment: Can you provide some code you have?

Comment: Which code exactly?I mean which files?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like ReactJS is the issue here - you need to understand how to 'get started' with OIDC. Maybe have a look at my initial tutorial as a next step, which recommends a security library, provides a code sample, then explains the end to end messages:

- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

Then update your original post with some more targeted questions ...

Comment: I am getting access_token in the url after authentication is completed.Something like this https://localhost:3000/?access_token=cQfvpiG45zwXUTiJ1gVDibcVvbcB1c&grant_id=ca268035-a19c-434a-b5fb-f8c79dbbeb1c    I want to read this access_token and then go to my dashboard page